# Как обновить «родителя категорий» в МойСклад?

Tags: php, api, moysklad-json-api, мойсклад-api, мойсклад

На сайте при редактирование категорий, можно менять родителя.
Для данного родителя у меня есть `externalCode`.

В [документаций](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) сказано что нужно обновить `$item->productFolder`.

Я пробую обновить так:

```
$item->name = $new['name'];
$item->description = htmlspecialchars_decode($new['description']);
$parent_id = 'cd1676e3-5a04-11e9-9ff4-31500040606a';
$item->relations->productFolder->fields->meta->href = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/productfolder/' . $parent_id;
$item->relations->productFolder->fields->meta->uuidHref = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#good/edit?id=' . $parent_id;
$res_ms = $item->buildUpdate()->execute();
```

Название и описание, меняються, а вот "категория родитель" - нет.

Можете подсказать как исправить?
Готов и через curl сделать запрос и обновить, только в документаций не достаточно информаций. Использую [SDK](https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad).

[issue](https://github.com/Tooyz/moysklad/issues/45)

Comment: Так-же при создание категорий, нужно указывать родителя, но не понятно как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -X PUT http://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product/b3839190-9992-11e9-ac12-000c00000154 -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{
"productFolder": {
    "meta": {
            "href": "http://localhost/api/remap/1.1/entity/productfolder/15c56d51-9a00-11e9-ac12-000c000001bc",
            "metadataHref": "http://localhost/api/remap/1.1/entity/productfolder/metadata",
            "type": "productfolder",
            "mediaType": "application/json",
            "uuidHref": "http://localhost/app/#good/edit?id=15c56d51-9a00-11e9-ac12-000c000001bc"
        }
    }
}'
```

Попробуйте через следующий запрос